# Variation in g acceleration due to gravity

Tags: celestial-mechanics, software

I want to find a routine which will enable me to calculate the variations in g
as a result of the motion of sun and moon. I need to have the date as a variable.
I realise that Dennis Milbert's earth tide routine must contain this information, but I
am reluctant to try to unpick his work. Where to go, please ?

Comment: There's some related info in Tom Van Baak's series of articles about the effects of tides on the period of precision pendulums. http://leapsecond.com/hsn2006/

Comment: Where you are on Earth will have a larger effect...